# 'Find My Mac' says that it is already in use, how to fully remove previous configuration?

Tags: macos, icloud, find-my-mac

I posted a question earlier about using [Find My Mac while my computer was sleeping](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44907/can-find-my-mac-work-while-the-computer-is-sleeping), and after doing some research I noticed that I had 'Wake for network access' already enabled. So when I went to check iCloud again, I noticed it saying this (Find My Mac already in use):

[image: Find My Mac already in use]

If I check the box, I then get this alert message:

[image: Will Disable for other user]

The only thing I can think of, is that I may have signed in with another iCloud account on this computer (I have an old iTunes account, plus a mobile me converted account that I actually use).

[bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike) mentioned he had see registration issues with Lion updates, and not sure if this was related to something similar, or to possibly linking this computer with another iCloud account originally. I want that original one gone, and only my new one to go.

My question is: **Is there any where else I should look for remnants of this 'other' iCloud account, to not cause other issues?** I know this was working at some point, even recently, so it confuses me on what happened here.

**Update:** So I went ahead and checked this, clicked Continue below, and it appears to work fine. I would still like to find what ID or anything else that would cause this though to help understand it if it happens again.

Comment: Do you still have any other user accounts on this machine? What happens if you sign out of iCloud and back in? More importantly, what happens if you click "Continue"?

Comment: No other user accounts. Have not signed out. Clicking continue prompts me for location info. I haven't gotten farther than that, hoping to get some feedback from this question first. As in, I am sure if I click though, things will 'just work', but I would like to remove whatever cruft I can as well

Comment: You might use `opensnoop` to figure out where it's reading data from — but my guess is that once you go through the setup process, you're not likely to see the problem again.

Comment: Ive actually used something similar like fsusage

Comment: And what was the result?

Comment: Way to much data flying by to get something easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this happen to me a couple of months ago.  I was perplexed, as you were, about what could be causing it.  I figured out the following, but as there's no information for this online it could be incorrect:

1. Find My Mac is tied to the serial number of your Mac
2. Find My Mac was partially enabled before iCloud was released
3. Since it was partially enabled, a previous MobileMe account could cause conflicts.

Again, I have no definitive proof for this.  But I got this notice on a fresh install of the operating system, *only* after upgrading my MobileMe account to an iCloud account.

So if I were you I wouldn't worry about it.  Most likely it's just a MobileMe bug that never got quite resolved.

Comment: This worked, and seeing that someone at least as seen the problem and doesn't seem to have any issues with it after the fact, will mark this as resolved. I do have beta/dev access, so it may have been something related to that.